# C# excel color text

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm currently using the below code to compare two csv files with each other. I can select a column in the file and it will compare the rows in that column, it then writes the incorrect and correct rows into another csv file. But now I want to change the color the text 'this row is not the same' so that it's more noticeable. How can I do this?

```
 public void comparing(int selectedRow, string filenaname, string filename2)
    {
          List<string> lines = new List<string>();
          List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename));
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename2));
            List<string> lijnen = new List<string>();
            string line;
            string line2;
            string differencesFile= @"C:\Users\Mylan\Desktop\differences.csv";

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null && (line2 = read.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                string[] split = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(csvSeperator));
                string[] split2 = line2.Split(Convert.ToChar(csvSeperator));


                if (split[selectedRow] != split2[selectedRow])
                {
                     lijnen.Add("This row is not the same:, " + line);
                }
                else if(test == test2)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The whole file is the same");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    lines.Add("This row is the same:, " + line);
                }                              
              }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(differencesFile, lines);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(differencesFile);
            reader.Dispose();
            read.Dispose();          
        }
        catch
        {

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a CSV file.   It won't be able to store Excel specific information, such as background colour.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's impossible to do what you want with CSV files. Excel reads only the values and separate these in columns, that's all.

If you want to create an Excel file directly by code, you need to use for example the Open XML :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/bb448854.aspx
This is what I use to create, edit Excel files (and Powerpoint files too). It's a bit tricky at beginning but it's a solution...